# Structuring and deploying node frontend and backend to Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a React project with two node apps:

- `Client`: Frontend code using React JS and Axios for making requests to my backend service.
- `API`: Backend service using Mongoose to connect to MongoDB and Express for handling restful requests.

I had a couple questions:

- Is it a best practice to create separate node applications like this for frontend and backend? I want to confirm this is a good setup.
- I've had some difficulties in deploying this to Google App Engine and could use some pointers.

What I've currently done:

- Added an `api.yaml` to my API service subdirectory.
- Deployed using `gcloud app deploy client/app.yaml api/api.yaml` which deploys two services (frontend and backend).

Is this a good approach?

If so, the challenge I'm now facing is that my API service is deployed to a subdomain and requests from my frontend are failing. Locally I am using the `proxy` value to proxy requests to my backend port on localhost, but I'm not sure how to modify my app to dynamically make backend requests to the correct subdomain when in the production environment (I also think CORS comes into play).

Comment: Can't comment on the overall architecture (i.e. having separate back and front end) but having different but related apps as services under the same project is okay. I'm not clear on why your backend requests have to be dynamic. Your front end is making calls to a known url (your backend service) right?

Comment: It needs to switch based on environment (localhost when running locally, https://api.somedomain.com when in production).

Comment: For such, you could use a variable so you'd have something like - ```const my_host = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? "https://localhost:8080" : "https://mydomain.example.com";```

Answer (score 3):

You need a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) file. The dispatch.yaml allows you to override routing rules. You can use the dispatch.yaml to send incoming requests to a specific service (formerly known as modules) based on the path or hostname in the URL.

Comment: This was the simplest solution and works splendidly. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted

Comment: Hi @djreed, Would you mind sharing your package.json file for your client folder and API folder ? I'm trying to do the same thing you did, but I'm struggling :)